# Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook

I keep getting the following error when trying to use my facebook integration deature on my xenforo forum.

> "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application
>   configuration."

My app id and secret are correct, and i added my domain, kinyo.org, to the app in facebook. Whats going on?

Answer (score 16):

For testing purpose just goto **app basic setting** and find **Website with Facebook Login** and put your localhost as below-

[image]

And in updating Facebook page 
[image]

Note- this is just for testing further you have to change site URL

Answer (score 10):

You will want to make sure your site url is set to the same callback url (used as the redirect_uri value passed to the graph api) within your facebook application configuration not the top level url of your site.

Facebook uses this uri as a validity check when returning a request token. If the uri that you  pass to the api as a callback handler does not match the site url in your application configuration, you will receive this error.

Comment: i cant find callback url option on the page

Comment: @chaitanyasaraf - Go to facebook developer and in your app, go to settings->Basic, there you should be able to see "Website with Facebook Login", you need to put your callback url there

Comment: I had a mixup between localhost and 127.0.0.1.  Changing the two to be consistent solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

in the facebook App Page, goto the basic tab. 
find "Website with Facebook Login" Option.

you will find Site URL: input there
put the full URL ( for example http://Mywebsite.com/MyLogin.aspx ). this is the URL you can use with the call like
If the APP ID is 123456789

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=http://Mywebsite/MyLogin.aspx&scope=publish_actions

Answer (score 3):

It was fixed. I was still redirecting to my localhost/ url from local testing. I switched it to the main url and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

For my AIR (AS3/Flex) applications to solve the issue i set the "*Settings*" > "*Advanced*" > "*Embedded browser OAuth Login*" to "**Yes**"

Comment: Thanks! This is what fixed the error for my flex FacebookMobile application.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also add your website? That´s more important than the app domain. You have to add a platform (choose "Website") and add the correct URL. The app domain is important if you have subdomains, so everything also works on those subdomains too.

Also, how is your fb.init code?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/