# Facebook API Login C# Desktop App

Tags: c#, facebook

I am trying to simply connect to the Facebook Graph using a C# console app, but am having a FacebookOAuth Exception. Here is my code so far:

```
       var client = new FacebookClient();

        // Exchange the code for an access token

        dynamic result = client.Get("/oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = "****************",
            client_secret = "*****************************",
            redirect_uri = "http://www.teamdavix.com",
        });

        // Read the auth values
        string accessToken = result.access_token;

        DateTime expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(result.expires));

        var query = "SELECT author_uid, page_id, message FROM checkin WHERE page_id = 357981198572";

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.q = query;
        dynamic results = client.Get("/fql", parameters);
        Console.WriteLine(results);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Where does the exception come from?

Comment: @JamieKeeling  My apologies. Error is from dynamic result = client.Get("/oauth/access_token"...)

Comment: @JamieKeeling Specifically, it says my redirect_uri is invalid. What redirect_uri should I use for a desktop-based app?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453683/invalid-redirect-uri-given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You have to use https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as the redirect_uri from desktop applications. The information from a successful login will be passed as url fragments (after a #) in the url. If there is an error it will be passed as query string parameters (after a ?) in the url.

http://www.hackviking.com/2014/11/facebook-api-login-flow-for-desktop-application/ - complete example how to implement a login flow from a desktop application.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2 - more information about how to build your own login flow.